# jqGrid multiple table columns sorting

Tags: php, ajax, json, jqgrid

in JqGrid, i enabled the multisort options and in grid view table i am fetching the columns from two table which having foreign key relation. The data is displaying correctly in view but when i sort using marks table columns, its displaying blank details.

only Student table column are getting sorted. the columns from Marks table are not sorting, its giving blank details.

```
url:'<?php echo $config['ajaxUrlPath'];?>json.php',
datatype: "json",
mtype: 'POST', 
height : 'auto',
colNames : ['Student Name', 'Email','10th %','12th %'],
colModel : [{name : 'name',index : 'name',width:100},
            {name : 'email',index: 'email',width:100},
            {name : 'tenthperc',index : 'tenthperc',width:100},
            {name : 'twelthperc',index : 'twelthperc',width:100},
           ],
rowNum : 10,
rowList : [10,20,30,50,100],
pager : '#pjqgrid',
sortname : 'id',
viewsortcols : [true,'vertical',true],
toolbarfilter : true,
viewrecords : true,
sortorder : "asc",
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you don't use `loadonce: true` option. So the sorting are implemented **in your server code**. You should examine exactly the values `sidx` and `sord` which send jqGrid to the server in case of multisort scenario. I suppose that your current server code use just the first part of `sidx` and it's the reason of your problem.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have not used sidx in json file.

Comment: @ChiruAdi: By the way, starting with 15 points of reputation you will get the right to vote up to 30 questions and answers **per day** (see [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5213/147495)). It's the most important right because the goal of stackoverflow is sharing good answers and questions. The searching engine use accepting and voting as the main searching criteria. So *if you will find any question or answer which helps you in any way* you should vote it up. In the way you will help other people to find the information on the stackoverflow.

Comment: Sure. I will vote up for useful question. Thanks for your answer its really is helped me.

Comment: @ChiruAdi: You are welcome! I explain you the common rules of the stackoverflow because I'm sure that you didn't followed there just because you didn't known there. I personally have enough large reputation which I can't use in any way. So I wanted just help you to understand stackoverflow better, so that you will get more good answers on your questions in the future. Best wishes.